# How can I map a domain to docker containers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nginx

I have a Redhat Linux server. In that, I installed docker and run docker containers in it. Now I want to map a domain to docker containers by using Nginx.

What is the correct process to map domains by using Nginx, install Nginx as a container or Install Nginx in the Host server? Any references?

Comment: With, uh, DNS? this question makes no sense as presented.

Answer (score 0):

**Basics**
Nginx is a webserver that can be used as a reverse proxy. I would suggest having a look at the nginx.conf file, where you can configure DNS redirects accordingly.

**Host**
Nginx on host means you would need a port mapping( host -> docker container) of all the docker containers in order to redirect traffic to the correct container. Wouldn't suggest this.

**Docker**
Nginx on docker on same docker network would be my suggested approach: you can use docker DNS and only map the nginx server itself(ports 80/443).

Maybe a tool based on nginx would help here, which already has lets encrypt support: https://nginxproxymanager.com/